# (count != null) vs if(!count) in javascript

Tags: javascript

I found this somewhere: Instead of `if (count != undefined && count != null)`, use `if(count != null)`. Can I use `if (count == null)` and `if(!count)` interchangeably?

Comment: `count != undefined && count != null` is *exactly* the same as `count != null`. `!count` is true if `count` is `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `NaN`, the empty string, or `false`. (Converted to an answer while I look for a duplicate)

Comment: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Answer (score 5):

`count != undefined && count != null` is *exactly* the same as `count != null`. `!count` is true if `count` is `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `NaN`, the empty string, or `false`.